# Yii2 - yiisoft/yii2-queue listen windows

Tags: php, windows, yii2, queue, web-worker

I am trying to implement my first system with Queue `yiisoft/yii2-queue` (to send background emails).

I am using `DB Driver`, so I realized I have to run `yii queue/listen` command for each time "to enter an queue" the email it is send to user. I am using `Windows OS` and putting `yii queue/listen` on the command line works, but if the command line closes the process ends.

From what I read in the documentation I should use "Starting Workers" but the recommended `Supervisor` and `Systemd` are for Linux only.
What is the best way to do this on Windows?

**common/models/SendEmail**

```
class SendEmail extends BaseObject implements JobInterface
{

    public function execute($queue)
    {
        Yii::$app->mailer->compose()
            ->setFrom('****')
            ->setTo('*****')
            ->setSubject('test')
            ->setTextBody('test')
            ->setHtmlBody('test')
            ->send();
    }
}
```

**app/controllers/NotifyController**

```
public function actionNotify()
    {
        Yii::$app->queue->push(new SendEmail([]));  
    }
```

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1167718/running-a-bash-background-process-on-windows-10-without-an-open-terminal/1274897

Answer (score 0):

You can set "yii queue/listen" up in Task Manager. Make it run when the windows starts.